# Multiple Post request CasperJS

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

I'm a beginner programmer in JavaScript and CasperJS and I'm hoping to make multiple post requests.

```
casper.then(function(){

  for(var i=0; i<30; i++){
        casper.open(address, {      
           method: 'post',
           data:   {
              'title': 'Hello',
              'body':  'Hello World ...'
           }
        });
    casper.back();
  }

});
```

Comment: The function did not make the post request

Comment: What's `address`? It must be a full URL.

Comment: I was able to get the program to run using a full URL, however, I'm now getting warning messages [warning] [phantom] Loading resource failed with status=fail: [site]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to make sure that `address` is a full URL (with `http://` and everything). Second, you need to use `casper.thenOpen()` instead of `casper.open()`, because the loop is too fast for `casper.open()` to be executed. Instead, it will overwrite multiple requests.